# Ambiguous use of operator '??'

Tags: swift

[This article](https://medium.com/@RobertGummesson/regarding-swift-build-time-optimizations-fc92cdd91e31#.u25j4jjs4) shows: `??` is very time-consuming, and the test found it to be true. So I want to optimize this:

```
#if DEBUG
public func ?? <T>(left: T?, right: T) -> T {
    guard let value = left else {
         return right
    }
     return value
}
#endif
```

**BUT**

```
string = string ?? ""
```

**ERROR**: `Ambiguous use of operator '??'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article you link to does not describe how the `nil` coalescing operator is *"time consuming"*, but states the simple fact that a compound expression of two `nil` coalescing operator calls as well as other evaluations has a significantly longer build time than if we break down this compound expressions into smaller parts, especially if the former contains lazy evaluations at some point (which is the case e.g. for the evaluation of the rhs of the `??` operator). By breaking down complex expression we help the compiler out; Swift has been known to have some difficulty compiling complex compound statements, so this is expected. This, however, should generally not affect *runtime performance*, given that you build your implementation for release mode.

By overloading the implementation of the `??` operator during debug with a non-lazy evaluation of the `lhs` *while still using long compound statements* shouldn't fully redeem the issue described in the previous clause. If compile time is really an issue for you, use the same approach as the author of the article; break down your complex expressions into several smaller ones, in so doing some of the work of the compiler yourself. Refactoring with the sole purpose of decreasing compile times (which we might believe is the job of the compiler, not us) might be frustrating at times, but is an issue we (currently) has to live with when working with Swift. See e.g. the following excellent article covering the Swift compiler issues with long/complex expressions:

- [Exponential time complexity in the Swift type checker](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/07/12/type-checker-issues.html)

---

W.r.t. to the ambiguity error: for reference, the official implementation of the `nil` coelescing operator can be found [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L608):

> ```
> @_transparent
> public func ?? <T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> T)
>     rethrows -> T {
>   switch optional {
>   case .some(let value):
>     return value
>   case .none:
>     return try defaultValue()
>   }
> }
> ```

And we may note that it has the same specificity as your own generic implementation (compare the signatures!), meaning the ambiguity error is to be expected. E.g., compare with:

```
// due to the '@autoclosure', these two have the
// same precedecence/specificity in the overload
// resolution of 'foo(_:)'
func foo<T>(_ obj: T) {}
func foo<T>(_ closure: @autoclosure () -> T) {}
foo("foo") // ERROR at line 9, col 1: ambiguous use of 'foo'
```

When you implement your `??` overload it as in your answer, typing out `Any`, this implementation becomes more specific than the generic one, which means it will take precedence in the overload resolution of `??`. Using `Any` is such contexts, however, is generally a bad idea, attempting to mimic dynamic typing rather than relying on Swift's renowned static typing.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.
I will break up the more time-consuming operators to improve the compile time. e.g.
for _ in [0..<100] {
 str = str ?? ""
}

Answer (score 0):

if I overloading `??`，I can't use `<T>`...

**then**

```
#if DEBUG
public func ?? (left: Any?, right: Any) -> Any {
    guard let value = left else {
        return right
    }
    return value
}
#endif
```

is **OK**!

**BUT** I can't get types of return value...